# Cron expression two times per month

Tags: c#, asp.net, cron

The following cron expression :

```
<cron-expression>0 0 6 1 1/1 ? *</cron-expression>
```

will run 06:00 AM on the 1-st day every month. But how to set this cron expression to run on the 1st day, and on the 16th day of every month?

Comment: You can use this to run on every 1st day of evey month 
0 0 6 1 1/1 ? * and for 16th day of every month 0 0 6 16 1/1 ? * or try if this works for a  combined check 0 0 6 1/16 1/1 ? *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
<cron-expression>0 0 6 1,16 1/1 ? *</cron-expression>
```